# Could Stack Overflow highlight the user who asked the question?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I think it would be a nice feature if the user that asked the question would be visually indicated when they add follow up post and comments. In my mind the user that asked the question has a special place or 'more significance' than other users.

For example on this question I asked the question. So, if I post an answer or message for this question, then add some type of indication to the post or name. A 'visual indication' could be anything such as a 'star' next to the name, some type of subtle highlighting.

Currently when I read a question on Stack Overflow I have to note the user that asked the question. I don't always succeed at doing this.

Comment: For example here the person who asked the question has posted a comment.  Please add some type of 'visual indication' to this post or to the user name.

Comment: I am not the post author.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is already in place.  Comments by the question author have the user's name shown with a grey background (not sure if this varies based on each site's color scheme).

> [image]

Comment: Wow, never noticed that. Perhaps it should be a *bit* more obvious ?

Comment: you learn something new every day

Comment: Ok, Cool.  I learned something today.  Thanks.

Comment: It's so faint now as to be useless to many people. I can't see it at all unless I am looking very closely.

Comment: @eddie_cat It varies a lot based on your monitor and its settings.  On one of my monitors it's very noticeable, while on the other I really need to be looking for it.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET it should [blink](http://www.montulli.org/theoriginofthe%3Cblink%3Etag), shouldn't it :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET It is kind of faint here on meta (`rgb(240, 240, 240)`), but on the main site (which is what the question is about) it's darker bluish gray `rgb(224, 234, 241)` -- if that one is not noticeable, monitor settings need work.

Comment: If people don't notice it, perhaps we should replace it with a randomly-generated, freehand-looking red circle (with a drop shadow).

Comment: Just calculated the contrast ratio of the gray box (#ECECEC) to the background (#FFFFFFF) Its a whoping: **1.18:1**. Needs to be more visible.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski thats sounds like a april fools joke they would make.